# c++ detect sources of bad allocations

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-management, lldb

I am writing a C++ application which has started to occasionally have what I believe to be bad allocations even though no bad alloc error is given. In one method, I have:

```
float * out = new float[len] //len works out to about 570000
memset(out, 0, sizeof(float) * len);
```

when this code runs, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at address `out[4]` (always the 4th element). In LLDB I tested the range of the error; turns out, I can never access/write to `out[n]` for any `4 <= n < 1028`.

I assume that there is some sort of allocation problem preventing me from getting clean access to this memory block, but I can't figure out how to find the responsible code. Any ideas where I can start?

I can provide more details if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `len` is 570000?  If you print it out right before the allocation what do you get?  Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: You probably have heap corruption from an earlier point in the program - try running under valgrind and/or enable address sanitizer.

Comment: Have you tried allocating something else and determining that it's the same memory block causing the issue? Try allocation char instead of float and see if index 17 is causing the same issue...

Comment: `len` comes to 573439 to be precise. As it turns out, if I replace the entire main function with the above and run no other code, it gets the same problem, with same memory addresses inaccessible. does this mean Xcode is somehow preventing me from making large allocations?

Comment: No - that's not a large allocation anyway - try enabling address sanitizer. I think we also need to see a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulR good point. Currently I have all the memory management options on, but address sanitizer is disabled (greyed out). However the problem has stopped occurring after rebooting my machine. Solved, but scary?

Comment: With the limited information available I'm going to guess that you have an issue with static initialisation - either way though you should definitely run with valgrind or address sanitizer to see if you still have latent memory bugs.

Comment: thanks for your help @PaulR . you're right, i'm not giving much info (doing my best). But I will update here if I find anything more precise that could be helpful.